# Another difference between Firefox and IE8 - viewPanel columns are not displayed the same

Tags: xpages

If you create a viewPanel and one of the columns wraps over multiple lines (see code below to see how I wrap the column), all the other columns move the text to the bottom of the row equal to the bottom of the wrapped column. In FF and Chrome, those same columns are at the top. **They want them at the top in IE**.

In the column I am doing the wrapping, I am using the following formula and I wonder if this makes a difference

```
<xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn4"
      contentType="HTML" width="150px">
     <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var valArr1 = new Array(view1.getColumnValue("SourceFileName"));
     valArr1.join('<br/>')}]]></xp:this.value>
     <xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader4"
          value="Original File Name">
     </xp:viewColumnHeader>
</xp:viewColumn>
```

The first screenshot shows the viewPanel in Firefox with the columns lining up at the top of the cell. The second screenshot shows the exact same view in IE8 and the columns lining up at the bottom of the cell.

[image: Firefox Screenshot]

[image: IE 8 Screenshot]

What can I change in the code/css to make the columns line up at the top in IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default my viewPanels do not act in that way so I wonder if there is an existing CSS which is causing the problem?

Use IE developer tools - SHIFT-F12 and inspect the style. Try changing it until you can get it to work on the page.

That said here's a suggestion to start
Assuming your viewPanel is called ViewPanel1

```
TABLE[id$='viewPanel1'] TR TD 
{
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a CSS Reset. A CSS Reset resets (sets) the styles of all elements to a baseline value so that you avoid cross-browser differences due to their built-in default style settings. By resetting your styles, you avoid defaulting to the browser’s built-in styles, which differs from browser to browser.

[CSSReset.com](http://www.cssreset.com/) contains the most common CSS Reset scripts.

You can of course customize your CSS Reset to the defaults that you need for your particular site (e.g. to match your requirements for vertical-alignment for table cells).

Once a CSS Reset has been applied, you can then work on your own CSS style (and hopefully avoid inconsistencies such as what you are experiencing here).

Comment: Per, I would love to take advantage of that option but under the current circumstances at my client and the time pressure to get the app. done and into production it is unlikely that I would have enough time to deal with it. I am better off "fixing" the issues IE8 causes than rebuilding OneUIv2.1 CSS

Comment: Roy, I understand that. And in most cases it should not be necessary since the OneUI css should take care of this. But for handling inconsistencies across browsers that OneUI does not handle, it can help to use a CSS reset to establish a default style across browsers.